# How to read data from npy file as TensorFlow dataset

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I have npy contains two ndarrays, one is a one-hot and the other one is the label. How can I input the data?

How to convert these data into x_train as a tensor? I only have experience on MNIST dataset and i don’t have to handle the input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MNIST datsets are loaded in a similar way as far as *.npy* arrays are concerned.

This line of code

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = 

 keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path="C:/Users/476458/.keras/datasets/mnist.npz")
```

in turn uses the following code.

```
path = get_file(path,
                origin='https://s3.amazonaws.com/img-datasets/mnist.npz',
                file_hash='8a61469f7ea1b51cbae51d4f78837e45')
f = np.load(path)
x_train, y_train = f['x_train'], f['y_train']
x_test, y_test = f['x_test'], f['y_test']
f.close()
return (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)
```

*np.load*  loads the *.npz* file which is a zipped archive which contains 4 *.npy* files ( x_train.npy, y_train.npy, x_test.npy, y_test ).

But you should be able to load a *.npy* file directly using *np.load*.

I hope this gives you some ideas.